# Strange .htaccess config on new hosting

Tags: .htaccess, cpanel

Recently I changed my hosting provider and I noticed strange lines of code in my public_html .htaccess file. The lines are:

```
# php -- BEGIN cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
# Set the “ea-php73” package as the default “PHP” programming language.
<IfModule mime_module>
  AddHandler application/x-httpd-ea-php73 .php .php7 .phtml
</IfModule>
# php -- END cPanel-generated handler, do not edit
```

Can somebody tell me what does are and can I get rid of them without something breaking out.

Thanks you for your time!

Comment: Why would you want to remove those lines? Sure, it would make more sense to have those in the actual http server's central host configuration. But in general it does make sense to connect requests to files with the mentioned file name extensions to the php engine. These lines make sure that php scripts get interpreted on the server side instead of being delivered to the requesting client.

Comment: On my  previous hosting I did not have this in my .htaccess and the site was working correctly, so I had no idea what it is for. I can just leave it there in my public_html's .htaccess and just write paste my previous .htaccess's config above it?

Comment: That is what the comments suggest. You should not touch that block, but certainly can modify the file itself, so outside that block. Certainly those lines are, as I already mentioned, not typical for a setup, especially for a shared hosting, usually such settings are done in the real http server configuration instead. But the shown setup is possible and certainly offers flexibility.

Answer (score 1):

This directive is or "might"<sup>***1**</sup> be required in order to process `.php` files with the appropriate PHP handler - in this case PHP version 7.3.

The fact this directive is in `.htacccess` allows you to configure (through cPanel) which version of PHP you want to use. So you can still run PHP that might require a specific/older version.

<sup>***1**</sup> Without this directive in `.htaccess` then your `.php` files will be processed using the server default - which maybe a different version of PHP. So it "may" still "work" without, or you may get some PHP errors/warnings/notices depending on your code base.